# Has_many through in Rails while assigning different roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to create a relationship between addresses and trips, and I'm not sure exactly how to set up the relationship.

Each trip will have two addresses: the starting address and the ending address. 
Addresses can be used in many different trips, and they can either be the starting address or the ending address depending on the trip. 
What I envision is that when users are creating a new trip, they can select from a dropdown of all their addresses, so they could make a trip from their address called, say, "home" to their address called, say, "airport."

There is already a polymorphic relationship set up between addresses (as locatable) with some other models in the app, but in this case the same address needs to belong to two different models (the user and the trip). Would a polymorphic join table be a good solution? Even if that did solve the problem, once you had connected two different addresses to trips, what's the best way to distinguish the starting address from the ending address?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Edit:
I have implemented everything below by hakunin, but I still cannot find a way to make the feature function. I decided to use `fields_for` to build the `TripLocation` objects for each `Trip`, but I cannot figure out what to put in the controller. When I put:

```
def new
  @trip = Trip.new
  @trip.origin_trip_location.build
  @trip.destination_trip_location.build
end
```

I get the error `undefined method build for nil:NilClass`. I was thinking of using just `@trip.trip_location.build` instead but then I get the error `undefined method trip_locations for #<Trip:0x007f5a847f94b0>` because in the model for Trip does not say `has_many :trip_locations`. By just using regular `has_many :trip_locations` 
I have been able to enter in all the information necessary into the join table just using the form helper `fields_for :trip_locations` and saying that a Trip `has_many :trip_locations`, but then I have no method to query and find which address has the boolean in the join table set as true and which one has it set as false. If I could just get that problem solved, I would be all set, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails this is normally done with a condition on the association. You can use it in combination with "has_one through". Create a new model, let's call it `TripLocation` which would be the mapping table between trips and addresses. In it you would have the column, say "destination". If the column is true, this mapping is for a destination address.

So let's say the migration looks like this:

```
create_table :trip_locations do |t|
  t.belongs_to :trip
  t.belongs_to :address
  t.boolean :destination
end
```

And these would be the models:

```
class TripLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :address
end

class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_one :origin_trip_location,
    class_name: 'TripLocation',
    conditions: { destination: nil }

  has_one :destination_trip_location,
    class_name: 'TripLocation',
    conditions: { destination: true }

  has_one :origin, through: origin_trip_location, source: :trip
  has_one :destination, through: destination_trip_location, source: :trip
end
```

So because of the conditions set on the "through" associations, calling `@trip.origin` and `@trip.destination` should give you the correct addresses.

When it comes to designating addresses as origin or destination, you can simply assign an address to whichever you need. `@trip.origin = Address.first`, or `@trip.destination = Address.second`, and I believe it should do the right thing with setting the destination flag. Try it.

Comment: I added these things, then I tried to add the lines to the form for creating trips where I assign an origin and a destination. Here is the error I am getting: `Could not find the source association(s) :destination or :destination in model TripLocation. Try 'has_many :destination, :through => :origin_trip_location, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :address or :trip?` I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the last 2 has_one lines. Instead of `class_name: 'Trip'` it should've been `source: :trip` since we are dealing with a "through" association.

Comment: Thank you, I have made that change. I am now trying to add the fields to the trip form where I assign addresses for origin and destination. What value should I pass from the address (its id?) and what should it be the input for? (I tried using `:origin` or `:origin_trip_location` but both give errors.) If you think that these questions are too far from the original post, or indicate that I have solved my original problem, let me know and I'll make a new question for this.

Comment: @KathrynB You're right, this is a slightly different question, more related to using rails form helpers like `select`, `collection_select` and friends. I suggest reading their documentation, perhaps that would be enough. Also, there are some security implications that you should be aware of when letting people select an id of an associated record (they shouldn't be able to inject any id they want), so if in doubt, make a new question. Feel free to link me there from here if you do.

Comment: I have asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739820/how-to-use-a-form-to-connect-has-one-through-relationship-with-condition Once I am sure everything is working I will mark this one correct.

Comment: I have been doing a lot more work on this and I am still not sure it works. I will add an edit to my original post.

Comment: Have you tried doing everything as I suggested, but using `destination_id` and `origin_id` form field names? Also note that using `origin_trip_location.build` is not going to work, because for `has_one` association the method for doing that is `build_origin_trip_location`.

Comment: Thank you the reply, I do have it working now and I have a much better understanding.

Comment: @KathrynB I know it's hard to form a specific question here, I think this type of learning is best done via tutorials, screencasts, blogs, and perhaps even pairing with someone. Glad you finally got it working .